# Can I flush the event stack within Firefox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, flush

I have a hierarchy of tags within my HTML which all contain `onclick` event handlers.  The `onclick` is pushed onto the event stack from the leaf back through the root of the hierarchy.  I only want to respond to the leaf `onclick` event.  Can I flush the event stack rather than using a flag?

For instance:

```
    <ul>
      <li onclick="nada('1');"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
      <li onclick="nada('2');"><a href="#2">2</a>
        <ul>
          <li onclick="nada('2.1');"><a href="#2.1">2.1</a></li>
          <li onclick="nada('2.2');"><a href="#2.2">2.2</a></li>
          <li onclick="nada('2.3');"><a href="#2.3">2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li onclick="nada('4');"><a href="#4">4</a></li>
      <li onclick="nada('5');"><a href="#5">5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Clicking on 2.2 using this function...

```
function nada(which)
  {
  alert(which);
  }
```

...will result in two alerts for '2.2' and '2'.

What  could I add to the nada function to eliminate the alert for '2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the event bubbling up to parent elements you have to tell the `event` object about it. In IE, you set `event.cancelBubble= true`. In other browsers, you call `event.stopPropagation()`.

You probably also want to turn off the default link-following action so that the browser doesn't keep jumping up to the top trying to follow the non-existing anchor links like `#1`. In IE, you set `event.returnValue= false`. In other browsers, you call `event.preventDefault()`.

The `event` object is accessible as `window.event` on IE. On other browsers, it is passed into the event handler function. A way to pass the event into a function that works on both is:

```
      <li onclick="nada('2.1', event);"><a href="#2.1">2.1</a></li>

function nada(n, event) {
    alert(n);
    if ('stopPropagation' in event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        event.cancelBubble= true;
        event.returnValue= false;
    }
}
```

However it would probably be better all round to put the `onclick` event on the `a` element which it usually belongs. This helps for accessibility, as the `a` element will be focusable and keyboard-operable. And it means you don't have to worry about parents' click handlers being called.

(You can style the `a` to look like a plain block, if you want.)

You can then also kick out the redundant `onclick` links with a bit of unobtrusive scripting:

```
<ul id="nadalist">
  <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">2</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#2.1">2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#2.2">2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#2.3">2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var links= document.getElementById('nadalist').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i= links.length; i-->0;) {
        links[i].onclick= function() {
            alert(this.hash.substring(1));
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you... event.stopPropagation(); ...was the key.

Comment: doesn't work if you add an event listener within an event listener, still gets executed immediately